# Update index of data in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String>` of length 4 like below -

```
{"ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL"}
```

In above `ArrayList` the `index` of data `ABC` is `0`, the index of data `DEF` is `1` and so on. Now, there is need that suppose we change the `index` of data `ABC` from `0` to `2` in that condition my `ArrayList` look like below

```
{"DEF","GHI","ABC","JKL"}
```

again I change in above the `ArrayList` the i`ndex` of data `GHI` from `1` to `4` my array look like below

```
{"DEF","ABC","JKL","GHI"}
```

In above discussion, I wanted to know that when I changed the index of a single data how can we get index of another data. I hope you will be understand my question.

I have a `ListView` in android that have drag and drop row. When drag and drop a row from position 0 to 3, then the position of another row will be change. How can we retrieve another row position.

Comment: can you please make your question more clearer?

Comment: It's unclear for me.

Comment: @Dropout thanks to understand my problem,yes it is duplicate of Moving items around ArrayList

Comment: @shaileshojha no problem, glad to help. The solution is there, I hope it's clear enough to understand from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method.

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

```
int indexOfAbd = yourList.indexOf("ABD");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use a `LinkedList` and whenever you need to modify the list

1. First store the element of initial index in a `temp` variable
2. Delete it from the list.`remove(int index)`
3. Use `add(int index, E element)` with the new index.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand your question correctly, you want to automatically keep track of the indices to existing array elements while you remove an element and add it at another position.

E.g. `[A, B, C, D]` has the indices `[A:0, B:1, C:2, D:3]`. Now you are removing A and insert it again at position 3: `[B, C, A, D]`. This results in `[A:2, B:0, C:1, D:3]`.

If this paraphrases your question correctly, then no, there is no automatic way to update the indices to existing elements while you are removing and inserting elements.

Note that there is `indexOf(x)`, which will search the list again for the *first* occurrence of `x`. If you are willing to pay the cost for the recurring search and if your elements are unique, this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Update an index does not make much sense per itself: the index is defined as the position of an item in an array. But you can:

- find an item in an ArrayList: `int indexOf(E item)`
- remove an item from an ArrayList: `E remove(int index)` or `boolean remove(E item)`
- insert an item at a given position in an ArrayList: `void add(int index, E item)`

If I have correctly understood your question, what you want to do could look like:

```
boolean changeIndex(String item, int index, List<String> lst) {
    boolean cr = lst.remove(item);
    if (cr == false) {
        return cr;
    }
    lst.add(index, item);
    return true;
}
```

This code returns `false` if the item was not present in `lst` and throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if index is negative (strictly) or greater (or equal) than the size of the array.

BTW, above code will work the same on any modifyable list, for example an ArrayList or a LinkedList - for operations like that, a LinkedList should be more appropriate